# Raspberry Pi server with Scoket/Python problem

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi, webserver, iot

I'm trying to create a simple web server with Raspberry Pi 4 - Model B using sockets in Python.
The problem is that I can request from any web browser in my loclal network and the server works, but when I try to request from an external network (different IP of the Raspberry Pi server) nothing happens.
I have read a bit about it and in most of cases the problem was solved writing as IP "0.0.0.0" in the bind method of the server code, but it didn't worked for me... Is there any other error?? please help me, I'm stuck

```
import socket #Importa la libreria Socket

message = "Hello Internet, I'm Here!!"#Message to send to the client

IP = "0.0.0.0"  #Listens to any IP client
PORT = 2020     #Server Port

mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mySocket.bind((IP, PORT))
mySocket.listen(5)

while True:
    
    print("\n"+"Waiting for a client...")
    client1, client1_addr = mySocket.accept()

    print("Got a request from client")
    request = client1.recv(1024)
    
    print("Sending Response...")
    http_response = b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n'
    client1.send(http_response)
    byts = bytes(message, 'utf-8')
    client1.send(byts) #Envia el mensaje al cliente
    print("Response sent!!!")
    
    client1.close()

    
mySocket.close()
```

Comment: Your router's firewall might block that specific port from being accessed from an external IP. Also it has no route to send the request, if you did not configured the router to do so.

Comment: If it works from your local network, the problem is probably not related to you code. To access your server from an external network, you have to configure a port forwarding on the router.

Comment: external request has to go through your local router (which you can configure) and through router of you Internet Provider (which you can't configure) - and most Providers block most ports for your security (so hackers can't access your computer). Usually port 80 and 8080 is open and you could try to use it instead `2020`. Eventually you can try to use programs like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which try to resolve it in different way but your program doesn't need any changes.